# How we call method before page is loaded in JSF?

Tags: jsf-2

```
@ManagedBean(name="bean")
@SessionScoped
public class MyBean{

@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct()
{
System.out.println("Inside post Construct");
}

public void beforePageLoad()
{
System.Out.println("Called before pageload for session scoped bean!!!");
}
}


How can we call beforePageLoad method everytime before the page loads.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

inside your page:

```
 <f:metadata>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.listener}"/>
 </f:metadata>
```

Comment: If we have an interface which has a method say prePageLoad(), if all our managed beans implement this interface, so to call this method do we have to write listener like phase listener, because we were thinking on using this approach across the framework, of calling a method in a bean before a page loads?

Comment: i would not tie each bean to perform such operation. i would create a single `PrePageLoadBean` with different listener methods to be executed in one or more pages

Comment: But will we not be violating DRY principle...Thanks for the reply..and helping out with your ideas..

Comment: pleased to help ;) using a single bean to accomplish analogous operations enforces DRY. you can (should) use the same listener on multiple pages/templates and you can use multiple listeners on a single page. keep in mind that JSF is very versatile, and this is just one strategy: there are infinte ways to do this and you should use what you feel more confortable.